# How can I hide the back button in Searchview

Tags: android, searchview

Does anyone know how to hide the back button in AppCompat v21 searchview? (outlined by green line)

[image: searchview back button]

I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

menu_main.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/v_home"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="180"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:title="Favorites"
    android:icon="@drawable/v_favorites"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        firstMenu = menu;


        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setActivated(true);


        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menuItemsVisibility(false);
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                menuItemsVisibility(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        menuItemsVisibility(true);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

// setting visibility of menu items on search
private void menuItemsVisibility(boolean visibility) {

    MenuItem homeItem = firstMenu.findItem(R.id.action_home);
    MenuItem favoriteItem = firstMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorites);
    MenuItem otItem = firstMenu.findItem(R.id.action_ot);
    MenuItem ntItem = firstMenu.findItem(R.id.action_nt);
    homeItem.setVisible(visibility);
    favoriteItem.setVisible(visibility);
    otItem.setVisible(visibility);
    ntItem.setVisible(visibility);
}
```

Note: the behavior showAsAction:Always and using methods menuItemsVisibility() to adjust the visibility of toolbar items is intentional.

Another Note: MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity and it also implements implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks from ObservableScrollView Library.

Comment: set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` in your activity. @James

Comment: I have already added getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); to my activity but the back button still appears

Comment: can you post your code here. I might be able to figure out. @James

Comment: I posted relevant code. @Pooja

Comment: I am a bit confused by your code. Your back button is coming from menu.xml? @James

Comment: the back button is part of SearchView. When user press the search button, the SearchView shows a back button which if the user presses make the searchView disappear. The back button is NOT a back button to previous activity. There is only one Activity in my app. The back button is part of SearchView.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding. Of course my answer won't work for you. @James

Comment: I tried to style SearchView and make the back button disappear but didn't work.

Comment: check this question it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348479/how-to-customize-the-up-button-when-the-searchview-is-being-expanded @James

Answer (score 5):

changed app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" to app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: It does nothing! I tried `ifRoom` and `always` for SearchView but it won't hide back button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410048/searchview-in-expanded-mode-doesnt-hide-all-action-bar-icons-starting-from-mars

Answer (score 1):

Use the method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

in order to remove the home button from the action bar.

Comment: `getActionBar()` will not work in Appcompat v7. @Hanish

Comment: I use AppCompat so getActionBar() throws an error. it should be getSupportActionBar() which doesn't work at all.

Comment: You are right actually I accidently pasted this instead of getSupport @Pooja

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly safe method because back button (navigation up) doesn't have id. But if you are using AppCompat with Toolbar, you can use this code to find it. It should be the first in the layout.

```
  int count = this.getToolbar().getChildCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        View v = this.getToolbar().getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
            return (ImageButton)v;
        }
    }
```

Call this method inside onPrepareOptionsMenu if you want to change drawable of that button.