# Change action provider back icon

Tags: android, icons

Action provider back icon:

[image: Action provider back icon]

How do i  change the back icon generated by the action provider.
I have already changed the back icon in all my activities with HomeAsUpIndicator.
But this generated back icon still with the default black arrow.
The image above show which icon i talk about, when i click on the search icon for example.

In my activity :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_equipment);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_chevron_left_white_48dp);
```

[...]

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.equipments_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchActionProvider searchActionProvider = new SearchActionProvider(this);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(searchItem, searchActionProvider);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with this line :

```
app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp"
```

Put it here :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_equipment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:title="@string/equipments"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `styles.xml` and add the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_close</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Still the same, but i use a NoActionBar theme, it is an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

get the SupportActionbar and specfiy the id of the icon

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
```

Comment: I already do that in my activity, but the icon generated when i active the action provider doesn't change.

Comment: make sure that  the right toolbar is set `setSupportActionBar(yourToolBar);`

Comment: take a look at this : [customize the up button when the searchview is being expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348479/how-to-customize-the-up-button-when-the-searchview-is-being-expanded)